# Unable to import different variant pricing using =IMPORTXML

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Can anyone advise how I can view pricing for multiple variants that use the same web page?

I have been able to use the formula =importxml(A1,"//p[1]/span[1]/span[1]") for items that only have one price, and that has been working for me. However, most of the products I want to compare have multiple variants. When I use this formula, I am only able to see the 2kg variant and not the others.

For example: https://www.jurassicbark-online.co.uk/products/acana-adult?_pos=1&_sid=284ff281e&_ss=r&variant=14087536050240

What should the formula be for each variant (2, 6, 11.4kg)?

Thank you all for your assistance!

=importxml(A1,"//p[1]/span[1]/span[1]") but I am only receiving the pricing for 2kg variant, not 6 or 11.4kg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2kg variant is the only price that is displayed in html. Prices of other variants are dynamically displayed using Javascript and are not accessible by `IMPORTXML`